# how to turn on and off kafka read messages when needed

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a spring application that reads messages from kafka, I want when I enable maintenance my application will not read messages from kafka anymore and when I turn off maintenance it will return to normal reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can invoke the pause( )/resume( ) on the KafkaListener. Refer

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#pause-resume